# Making a folder with incrementing number depending on existing folders with same name

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch file which creates a folder with an incremented number when there is one already existing with the same name.

For example for a folder called `folder` something like this:

```
if exist folder md folder1 if exist folder1 md folder2
```

What I want is to make another folder with an incremented number at the end when there are already 1 or more folders with the same name (folder1, folder2, ...) and make the code shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This batch code is based on your initial idea:

```
@echo off
set "Folder=C:\Temp\Test"
if not exist "%Folder%" (
    md "%Folder%"
    goto EndBatch
)
for /L %%N in (1 1 65534) do (
    if not exist "%Folder%%%N" (
        md "%Folder%%%N"
        goto EndBatch
    )
)
:EndBatch
set "Folder="
```

But this solution is VERY slow with several folders already existing.

Much faster is following batch file:

```
@echo off
set "Folder=C:\Temp\Test"
if not exist "%Folder%" (
    md "%Folder%"
    goto EndBatch
)
set "FolderCount=0"
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /AD /B "%Folder%*"') do set /A FolderCount+=1
md "%Folder%%FolderCount%"
set "FolderCount="
:EndBatch
set "Folder="
```

But this batch file does not really check the folder names. It just counts the number of folders starting with same string and expects that for new folder the next number can be used. This could be a wrong assumption for example with `C:\Temp\Test1` deleted and `C:\Temp\Test` and `C:\Temp\Test2` still existing. The batch file above tries to create nevertheless `C:\Temp\Test2` in this case.

A better batch file would be therefore this one:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ParentFolder=C:\Temp"
set "FolderName=Test"
if not exist "%ParentFolder%\%FolderName%" (
    md "%ParentFolder%\%FolderName%"
) else (
    set "HighestNumber=0"
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /AD /B "%ParentFolder%\%FolderName%*"') do (
        set "NameFolder=%%~F"
        set "FolderNumber=!NameFolder:%FolderName%=!"
        if !FolderNumber! GTR !HighestNumber! set "HighestNumber=!FolderNumber!"
    )
    set /A HighestNumber+=1
    md "%ParentFolder%\%FolderName%!HighestNumber!"
)
endlocal
```

It is also fast because also not checking existence of each folder. But it really finds out what is the highest number of all folders starting with same string and creates a new folder with next number.

**Note 1:** This batch code is also not 100% fail safe. For example a folder `C:\Temp\Test_New_15` could be a problem for this batch file expecting only `C:\Temp\Test`, C:\Temp\Test1`, C:\Temp\Test2`, ... being found. (`Test_New_15` is ignored, but something similar could be a problem.) It would be of course possible to eliminate this problem for example with using additionally `findstr` on every line returned by `dir` to check if after string defined by **FolderName** nothing else than a number is appended.

**Note 2:** A folder number with a leading **0** is interpreted as octal number. It would be necessary to remove leading zeros if there are folders with 1 or more leading **0** on value of **FolderNumber** before the `if` condition.

To understand the codes in the 3 batch files, open a command prompt window, execute the following commands, and read help output in the window for each command.

1. `dir /?`
2. `for /?`
3. `goto /?`
4. `if /?`
5. `md /?`
6. `set /?`
7. `setlocal /?`

Comment: If somebody is interested in reason for value __65534__ read Microsoft TechNet article about [Working with File Systems](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457112.aspx) and look on __Table 13-6 FAT32 Size Limits__ with __maximum number of files and subfolders within a single folder__. I observed that many applications stop working properly if folder __%TEMP%__ reaches 65534 number of files and subdirectory entries even on an NTFS partition. Then it's about time to use the [Windows Disk Cleanup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/delete-files-using-disk-cleanup).

Comment: I just tried the second code (as you said: the faster one) and it works perfectly!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the previous folder ONLY if it's empty?
If there is, please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

There are better/faster ways of creating increasing folder names (and some of them are at Mofi`s answer!), but as the indicated criteria is short code, here is an alternative (but as Mofi indicates, this can be a slow solution)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folderName=test"

    2>nul (md "%folderName%"||cmd /q /c"for /l %%a in (1 1 100000) do md "%folderName%%%a"&&exit %%a")
    if errorlevel 1 set "folderName=%folderName%%errorlevel%"

    echo Created %folderName%
```

Comment: Ok. That works. But what if I wanted to make a "modsBackup" folder in %AppData%\.minecraft\ ? What would the code look like?

Comment: @TomLenc, `set "folderName=%AppData%\.minecraft\modsBackup"`

Comment: Thanks! But I need one more thing.. How do I make automatic removing of the "modsBackup" folder NO MATTER WHAT NUMBER IT HAS made by the command but ONLY when it's empty(because in my program it copies files to the folder, but sometimes it's not working. That's why..)?

Comment: @TomLenc, If you have not stored the folder name, try to delete all. `2>nul (for /d %%a in ("%AppData%\.minecraft\modsBackup*") do rd "%%~fa")` Only empty directories will be removed. Or search here. There is a lot of questions about searching for the last file/folder.